# (Eclipse) move item to top of listveiw

Tags: android, eclipse

i create custom listveiw but item of list go bottom of list

my activity xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ir.sheikhoo.sis.ListuniActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="@string/list_activity_btn_cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReload"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="@string/list_activity_btn_ok" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutBottom"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_university_white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/uniName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:text="@string/list_title" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/next_ic"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/next_ic"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have `android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutBottom"` on your ListView. Since it is wrapping content, it only wraps the vertical content that is inside of it, and since you have it constrained above the button linear layout, it's staying there. You probably want to remove the `above` constraint and  try adding `android:alignParentTop="true"` on your ListView

Comment: Tnx, i remove `android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutBottom"` in listview then put listveiw in LinearLayout and put `android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutBottom"` in it